# How to get a tooltip like balloon on click of a button using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

am pretty new to jquery. I need to bring out a balloon on double clicking a word. (exactly like a google dictionary). Can anyone help me ..

awaiting for positive response.

Thanks in advance,
Sruthi.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a `dblclick` event that you listen for and take action.  For example:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('p').on('dblclick', function() {
            //Show the tooltip here.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's a live example of this - http://jsfiddle.net/5Xj7A/

The jQuery UI official tooltip plugin is in 1.9 which has yet to be released, but there are a ton of jQuery tooltip plugins you can to implement the actual tooltip depending on what you're looking for.  There's a big list here - http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/.